# Search and replace string under specific line

Tags: python, replace, find

How can I do a search AND REPLACE a string. To be more specific.

I have a text file with

```
SAMPLE  
AB  
CD  
..  
TYPES  
AB  
QP  
PO  
..  
RUNS  
AB  
DE  
ZY
```

I want to replace `AB` with `XX`, only under lines `SAMPLE` and `RUNS`. I've already tried multiple ways of using `replace()`. I tried something like

```
if 'SAMPLE' in line:
    f1.write(line.replace('testsample', 'XX'))
if 'RUNS' in line:
    f1.write(line.replace('testsample', 'XX'))
```

and that didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A file is an iterator over lines in Python:

```
for line in file:
    output.write(line) # save as is
    if 'SAMPLE' in line or 'RUNS' in line:
       line = next(file, "") # move to the next line
       output.write(line.replace('AB', 'XX')) # save replacing AB with XX
```

To support SAMPLE/RUNS lines that follows another SAMPLE/RUNS line e.g.:

```
SAMPLE
SAMPLE
AB
```

you could:

```
for line in file:
    output.write(line) # save as is
    while 'SAMPLE' in line or 'RUNS' in line:
       line = next(file, "") # move to the next line
       output.write(line.replace('AB', 'XX')) # save replacing AB with XX
```

Comment: You should understand that this would replace 'AB' with 'XX'  even if AB is part of Line (CRAB -> CRXX).

Comment: @oleg: yes. Do you see any indication in the question that it should be otherwise?

Comment: No but task formulation seems ambiguous for me. and I decide to draw attention to this aspect.

Comment: Also, this code will raise an exception if `SAMPLE` is the last line of the file.

Comment: @kirelagin: I've added code that handles SAMPLE being in the last line

Comment: @kirelagin: if the file is not supposed to end with SAMPLE, then it's fine to raise an exception - errors should never pass silently, you know.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way will be to iterate your file line by line, and each time you see a `SAMPLE` or `RUNS` line to save a flag meaning “the previous line was the one I was looking for”. Any other line will reset this flag. Now on every iteration you check if the flag was set during the previous iteration, and if it was you do your `.replace` thing.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't want the lines below `SAMPLES` replaced and you don't want to replace a line that contains `ABC`, this would be a bit more robust if your file contains more text per line than the strings you are looking for.

```
valid_sections = set(('RUNS', 'SAMPLE'))
for raw_line in fobj_in:
    clean_line = raw_line.strip()
    if clean_line in valid_sections:
        fobj_out.write(raw_line)
        raw_line = next(fobj_in)
        clean_line = raw_line.strip()
        if clean_line == 'AB':
            fobj_out.write(raw_line.replace('AB', 'XX'))
        else:
            fobj_out.write(raw_line)
    else:
        fobj_out.write(raw_line)
```

Comment: `clean_line in valid_sections and clean_line == 'AB'` is always `False` in your code for any input.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Fixed that. Need to go to the next line to search for `AB`.

Comment: you need to add stripped newlines back.

Comment: I write only `raw_line`, i.e. the non-stripped line. The `clean_line` is not written only used for checks.